# Keep on receiving a white label error on my spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle

this is my controller class

```
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 Import org.springframework.ui.Model;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class Place {


@RequestMapping(value="/chooseaplace")
public String place(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("choose","place");
    return "place";

}}
```

what is the error as I've been sorting it out for 4 hours but still failed?

```
when I run my application what happens is I get a message like this
```

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Feb 05 14:24:21 GMT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

I want the page to display a simple message but it won't work?

Comment: what error are you talking about? Is model supposed to be a RequestParam?

Comment: have you checked your logs to see what goes wrong?

Comment: its not really helping me what do you think might be causing the error?

Comment: We do not have much info to go on.
What did you already check when trying to fix this? - Are you sure your controller is being picked up by component-scanning?
- Did you check the log to see if the request-mapping-handler register a request-mapping for your controller?
- Did you verify your URL?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have the resource place.html in the places where spring will look for resource.

Verify that you have resource in src/main/resources/static or src/main/resources/public directory in your packaged war.